# How to print attribute of constructor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

**Need to print-list inside the constructor Student Self.grades=[ ] empty list
when trying to access it is printed out the object of address**

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.grades = [] # how to print this


    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if type(grade) is Grade:
            k = self.grades
            k.append(grade)

class Grade:
    minimum_passing = 65
   
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score
        


pieter = Student("pw", 10)

pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
```

PS thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `grade.score`:

```py
k.append(grade.score)
```

Print list:

```py
print(pieter.grades) # [100]
```

See also [Python class examples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables).

Answer (score 0):

If you append items to list then you need `for`-loop to display attribute from all elements on list

```
for item in pieter.grades:
    print(item.score)
```

and it will print every score in new line

```
pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(16))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(56))

for item in pieter.grades:
    print(item.score)

100
16
56
```

If you use list comprehension then you may convert it to list

```
scores = [ item.score for item in pieter.grades ]
print(scores)
```

and it will display it as list

```
pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(16))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(56))

print([ item.score for item in pieter.grades ]) 

[100, 16, 56]
```

---

You could add this as method in Student

```
 def get_scores(self):
     return [ item.score for item in self.grades ]
```

and use as

```
for item in pieter.get_scores():
    print(item)  # without .score

print(pieter.get_scores())
```

---

Full code

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.grades = [] # how to print this


    def add_grade(self, grade):
        if type(grade) is Grade:
            k = self.grades
            k.append(grade)

    def get_scores(self):
        return [ item.score for item in self.grades ]
    
class Grade:
    minimum_passing = 65
   
    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score

pieter = Student("pw", 10)

pieter.add_grade(Grade(100))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(16))
pieter.add_grade(Grade(56))

for item in pieter.grades:
    print(item.score)
    
print([ item.score for item in pieter.grades ])

for item in pieter.get_scores():
    print(item)

print(pieter.get_scores())
```